# How to create and check block revisions?

Tags: 8, blocks

How to create and check block revisions ? I can see the option at bottom while creating a block but when I click to see the revisions the link doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem, cannot even see the "Revisions" tab like I do with content. Which link are you clicking that doesn't work? Please add screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

The revisions checkbox on blocks doesn't do anything yet, in fact I think it may have been removed. Block revisioning is being proposed for Drupal 9's generic revision UI. For the latest, please see [this post on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1984588).

Comment: Following the post in this answer it seems an avenue for accessing block revisions in the interface was not added to Drupal 9 and has in fact been postponed.  The last post in the thread is 3 years old!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Drupal 10, according to [this post on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1984588) as of January 8, 2023.